# A library is not found when installing RPM, although it's not true

Tags: fedora, rpm

I have an app that didn't have an RPM, so I converted it from DEB and trying to install it (so it probably could have some issues).
It requires dependencies which I already installed separately. Should I do something with RPM itself?
[image]

Comment: can you copy and paste the error text instead of an image and click on the "code formatting" button, labeled `{}`? This is hard to read as image.,

Comment: Converting from a .deb to a .rpm loses a lot of information, such s other rpm dependencies. You can try to rebuild the rpm but you will need access to the source code (tar.gz or zip) and a list of dependencies.

Comment: If you have a DEB, you might consider running the app in some kind of container, e.g., docker, VirtualBox, etc.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263444/missing-libraries-in-my-rpm-but-i-know-they-are-there

Answer (score 3):

Those dependencies are *not* installed as far as RPM is concerned. You copied files onto the machine, but didn't install the RPMs, so there are no entries in its database, *e.g.* `rpm -qa | grep liblber`

You need to either install these tools properly from RPM or do everything source/tarball-based. You can't (easily) mix and match these two methods.